# I need to use the apk as a library but getting error resource not found

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have a resource that is being used in Project A that can be found in my apk external library Project B.

I dont want to add the whole project B to my project A as I am trying to get Project A to only pull the maven m2 repo Project B file. How can I still get this to work?

```
<resources>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="CoreTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go   here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

part of my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.apptricity.android-core:android-core:7.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an APK (which uses the Gradle plugin statement `apply plugin: 'android'`) for a library that something else depends on. You can only depend on a library, i.e. `apply plugin: 'android-library'`.

If you need Project B to be both a library and generate an APK, then you'll need to refactor the library part of it out into C, and have A and B depend on it.